# Does Angular $location service support multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular's `$location.search()` method, it is possible to create a URL parameter, like this:

```
http://mysite.com/page?param=myParam
```

Is it possible to create multiple URL parameters, like this?

```
http://mysite.com/page?param=myParam&param2=myParam2&...
```

I've tried adding multiple object parameters to the function call (ex. `$location.search({ key1: value, key2: value })` ), but I'm only receiving one key/value in the URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PHnLb/42/

```
$scope.changeTarget = function(name) {
    $location.search({target : 'Hi', new : 'else'});
}
```

(Angular 1.1.4, HTML5 mode = true)

Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: We're using Angular 1.1.4. Maybe it's a version thing. The Angular changelog doesn't seem to go that far (1.1.6), though - do you know where i might find this info?

Comment: Found the issue. I'm working on this as a company project, and it looks like the $watch function that has been written limits you to one query var. Not an angular issue.

Comment: Sorry, I meant angular 1.1.4. Confused it with 1.0.6 Glad you could solve your issue. I would also welcome you to accept my answer, as I technically answered your questioned successfully. ;)

Comment: Be careful, it seems that when passing an object as a parameter angular replaces the full search object, i.e. doesn't just replace the mentioned one like when only one querystring param is passed!